# Macbook cannot install hexo

Tags: node.js, hexo

Here is the log:

```
npm ERR! Error: read ETIMEDOUT  
npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:863:11)  
npm ERR!     at TCP.onread (net.js:524:19)  
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:  
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>  
npm ERR! or email it to:  
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>  
npm ERR! System Darwin 14.1.0  
npm ERR! command "/Users/JianqingJiang/~/nvm/v0.10.0/bin/node" "/Users/JianqingJ  
npm ERR! cwd /  
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.0  
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.14  
npm ERR! syscall read  
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT  
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT  
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
```

I install the *git* and *node.js* and looks good but when I want to install hexo, the error shows up.

Comment: Please post the command that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, full command would help.  I will assume that you were doing `npm install hexo`...

What can be deduced here is that npm tried to obtain the`abbrev` package (the first dependency of `hexo`, btw)  and the HTTP request timed out.

So you should check your network connection etc (proxies ...) and try again.  I just installed here without issue.

Comment: Can you try to install some thing smaller and not globally?  Something like `cd ~; mkdir testnode; cd testnode; npm install abbrev` and see if it works? It should be very fast as `abbrev` is a small package.  You can then simply delete the `testnode`directory.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: sh-3.2# npm install abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev/-/abbrev-1.0.7.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev/-/abbrev-1.0.7.tgz
abbrev@1.0.7 node_modules/abbrev
Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: I am stumped. The segfault is not a good sign but http seemed to have worked.  Since you use `-g` with hexo, could it be that some directories in your node_modules belong to root (you could have sudo `npm install -g` at some point in time). Otherwise, I out of ideas.